# Drupal add an action on the content listing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is it possible to add an action on the /admin/content page. We got "publish selected content" or "delete selected content" etc etc...

http://screencast.com/t/v2ZMedCqy3g

I'm trying to add an action here from a module installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement [`hook_node_operations()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_operations/7). You can look at the `pathauto_node_operations()` as example.

```
function pathauto_node_operations() {
  $operations['pathauto_update_alias'] = array(
    'label' => t('Update URL alias'), 
    'callback' => 'pathauto_node_update_alias_multiple', 
    'callback arguments' => array('bulkupdate', array('message' => TRUE)),
  );
  return $operations;
}
```

Notices that the callback specified takes an array of node ids, plus the additional callback arguments as you specified in your hook implementation (see above example).

```
// The call back specified above ^
function pathauto_node_update_alias_multiple(array $nids, $op, array $options = array()) {
  $options += array('message' => FALSE);

  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    pathauto_node_update_alias($node, $op, $options);
  }

  if (!empty($options['message'])) {
    drupal_set_message(format_plural(count($nids), 'Updated URL alias for 1 node.', 'Updated URL aliases for @count nodes.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: it's look that, but how can i add something? Got you an example?